# Connecting micro USB phone into USB-C integrated slot in a car

Tags: usb, low-power, usb-c

I have a USB-C female port in my car and my smartphone only has a micro USB connector. Is there any risk to plug my phone in with a micro USB/USB-C adapter?

I know that USB-C can deliver up to 100 W of power and I'm not sure if the integrated USB-C device in my car will be "smart" enough to limit the power delivered. I cannot find any information in the car manual neither find a definitive answer on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine; at standard USB 5V levels, your device will only draw as much current as it needs.  The higher voltage power delivery levels must be requested by the powered device.